# Set environment variable for current process in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, environment-variables

I'm working on a spring(with maven) project. I want to customize my spring boot banner. In my banner.txt file, I can access some specified banner variable [`ref`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-banner) as well as system environment variable like JAVA_HOME.

My banner.txt file

```
:: Spring Version :: ${spring-boot.formatted-version}
:: Java Home :: ${JAVA_HOME}
```

I want to show some more info from my current process in my spring boot banner. So I'm trying to find out a way to set some variable to the environment for the current process. So that I can access them from my banner.txt like ${JAVA_HOME}. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `Banner` *interface* to customize the banner, for example:

```
public class CustomBanner implements Banner {
    @Override
    public void printBanner(Environment environment, Class<?> aClass, PrintStream printStream) {
        printStream.println("|==================================|");
        printStream.println("|----------My Demo Module----------|");
        printStream.println("|==================================|");
        printStream.println("|>>> Java Home  : " + environment.getProperty("JAVA_HOME"));
        printStream.println("|>>> Process Id : " + ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());
    }
}
```

With `environment` variable you can retrieve any system environment variable as `JAVA_HOME`. With `printStream` variable you can customize the output.

And finally you must modify your class boot, for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
        app.setBanner(new CustomBanner());
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
|==================================|
|----------My Demo Module----------|
|==================================|
|>>> Java Home  : /usr/bin/java
|>>> Process Id : 14548@Juans-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables for current process like `${JAVA_HOME}` is too much for your case.

First think about:

1. Passing variables in `.properties` or `.yml` files
2. Passing variables in maven properties:

   `<property>banner url</property>`
3. Passing command-line arguments

   `java -jar <argument> <jar>`

If you want something more flexible in runtime you can investigate docker data containers.

Comment: Thanks, @Sergey Rybalkin Actually, I'm working on a multi-module project. Each child module has some similar field(like productTitle) but different value. And I've one common application properties file. When I run my project, I want to show that similar field value(obviously different value for each child module) in my spring boot banner. So I just want to set those field/variable to the environment of the running process and call them in my banner.txt file.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand you completely. But logging jvm arguments is simple with `XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`. Print boot properties is also simple. What is your problem?